# Tooltip is not displaying in its position

Tags: css, angularjs, html

after adding 7 entries i'm getting a scroll bar. so if i scroll down the bar then the tool tip for each entries is displaying in some other places.

i'm using CSS property for this.if i'm not using position fixed the tool tip is displaying behind the screen

```
 " position:fixed;"

$scope.showDescriptionTooltip = function(index){
    //console.log("Inside showToolTip..." + $scope.displayToolTip + "   index :: " + index);
    if(index == $scope.displayToolTip){
        $scope.displayToolTip = -1;
    } else {
        $scope.displayToolTip = index;
    }   
    //console.log("$scope.displayToolTip ::" + $scope.displayToolTip);
};


 <div ng-init="hideTooltip[$index]=1" ng-click="toggleTooltip($index, $event);" class="menu-toggle-black" style="float:left;margin-top: 10px;" ng-hide="deleteThresholdFlags[$index]==true||editThresholdFlags[$index]==true||addModeSelected==1 || item.enable=='false'">
                        <ul class="menu-tooltip margin-left-140px" ng-show="showTooltip[$index] == 1">
                            <li ng-apply-privilege="VRM_ADD_THRESHOLD" style="width:69%;color:#0095d3;font-weight:bold;font-size:19px;" class="logout" ng-click="editButton($index);"><span style="float:none;"><a translate="settings.view.EDIT"></a></span></li>
                            <li ng-apply-privilege="VRM_DELETE_THRESHOLD" style="width:69%;color:#0095d3;font-weight:bold;font-size:19px;" class="logout" ng-click="deleteButton($index);"><span style="float:none;"><a translate="settings.view.DELETE"></a></span></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Please share JSFIDDLE URL

Comment: please share HTML and CSS code..

Comment: i added a the HTML code @shanidkv .

Comment: pls give me a solution for this. the tooltip should be displying on top of the screen and want to display on the correct nob even after scroll down. now i'm facing issue after scroll down the scroll bar the too tip is not displaying in that appropriate nob.

Comment: If i'm using "position:relative" the tooltip is displaying in correct nob even after scroll down but the tool tip is displaying behind the screen. i'm not able to add the screen shots.otherwise i'll add. the will be more precise to understand .

Comment: Any one can help me out from this issue?

Comment: please any one can tell me the solution for this issu